# writing IDE or text editor in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ide, macos

I'm thinking about writing an IDE or text editor for scripting languages such as ruby, python etc...Is there a framework which will get me started? For now, I just want to have basic features like code completion, syntax highlights

Comment: Code completion and syntax highlights are not basic features. They require runtime parsing and partial understanding of the language, the code and all the code it imports.

Comment: The first thing is that you have to make a better editor than Xcode, Vi or Emacs which are free. Then would need to make a better one than TextMate which cost but is highly extensible. Unless you're just doing this for an exercise, I wouldn't bother. Code editors are done to death.

Comment: Code Completion and Syntax Highlighting are some of the last things I would call "basic".  Note the distinct lack of available Cocoa libraries that do them...

Comment: A year has passed. How far did you get with this project?

Answer (score 6):

Code Editors are done to death so unless you have a genius idea or just want to use it as a professional exercise, I wouldn't waste time.

Every programmer dreams of writing our own editor and most of use attempt it at one time or the other but most of us give up owing to suprising amount of time such an apparently simple tool takes to produce. Those that don't give up eventually commit seppuku. Actual code editors are handed down from on high by divine beings because they are the only creatures with the eternal patients to get the job done.

If you want to risk it anyway, I would suggest starting with the [Introduction to Text Editing in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/TextEditing.html) and work you way out from there.

However, since the real killer in Code editors is parsing syntax, you might want to look at [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/) which will let you create Cocoa apps with Ruby. Using Ruby would help greatly with parsing because large scale parsing in Objective-C is a death march. There are also some public domain parsers written in Ruby for [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)

Heed my bitter voice of experience.

Answer (score 1):

The Scintilla project might give you a good start. Lots of popular editing tools (Notepad++, Code::Blocks, and the like) use this as their base.

[The Scintilla Project](http://www.scintilla.org/)

Perhaps you ambitions would be better suited to contributing to this project?